# CSS hover prevent child from affected

Tags: css

I have the following div stricture.

```
<div class="profile_outer>
   <div class="profile"></div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS

```
.profile_outer {
    border: 2px solid #660000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.profile {
    width: 198px;
    height: 225px;
    border: 1px solid #660000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
 }

 .profile_outer:hover {
background-color: blue;
 }
```

you can find the [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PdQFJ/)

Both divs do not have a background, the background is determined by an image on some parent div. So they are transparent.

So, on a hover I just want to change the background of the outer profile. It only works if I also change the background color of the inner div using

```
.profile_outer:hover .profile {
display: block;
background : #fff; // but I do NOT want to change the background
}
```

I tried the following combinations of these:

```
.profile_outer:hover .profile {
display: block;
background : none !important;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess that the effect that you want is this

```
.profile_outer {
    border: 2px solid #660000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.profile {
    width: 198px;
    height: 225px;
    border: 1px solid #660000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
 }

 .profile:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1000px blue;
 }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJpbG/1/)

... but you should review your ideas about transparency ...

After re-reading the question, I think that Moob's sugestion is right, the answer to the question is

```
.profile_outer:hover .profile {box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1000px blue;}
```

Comment: +1, clever solution. Although I think the OP actually wants `.profile_outer:hover .profile {box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1000px blue;}` (http://jsfiddle.net/gJpbG/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the child's background to #fff and it'll work.

Your problem happens because the default background color for all elements is transparent

Comment: I tried that but I do not want that. I want all transparent except the outer div. So it is highlighted.

Comment: But what does transparent means to you? if a transparent element is on top of a blue background element, it will inevitably show the blue of the parent

Comment: OK, none of the divs have a background. only the outer div should have a background when hovered. maybe this is not possible ?

Comment: Well if anything under a transparent object becomes non-transparent of course everything below it will be hidden it.
What do you want to archive? There is probably some way to do it, just not this.

Comment: I understand that, I need to find a way to override the parent background back to the higher level parent transparency

Comment: Such paradigm is not possible within our physical world, transparent means you can see through it and if you can see through it, Hence perhaps it's not the right question. What i assume you're asking is how can you get to the top level background with your inner element, and a possible solution might be using sass (for consistency, normal css also works) http://jsfiddle.net/UHMr6/

Another way could be just giving the internal div a very large border with a diffirent color, hence leaving it transparent: http://jsfiddle.net/UHMr6/1/

Comment: Just another possible way is to give the colored big border to the containing (transparent) element, thus keeping transparency to the first level: http://jsfiddle.net/UHMr6/2/

Answer (score 0):

There is one other way to get this effect but it could be really annoying to implement. I'm only offering it up as a solution for completeness. Effectively you have the SAME background image on the bit that is supposed to appear masked:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    background:#fff url('http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-5.jpg') 0 0 repeat;
}
.profile_outer {
    margin:20px; /* added this just to show that you'd need to offset the image placement in .profile depending on its position */
}
.profile {
    background:#fff url('http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-5.jpg') -20px -20px repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PdQFJ/1/